# CSS Links and hover operations?

Tags: css, hyperlink

Have a page to install links to other sites with link inputs as follows:

```
<div id="mainContent">
         <div id="links">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="blank">Go To Google</a>
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="blank">Go To Yahoo</a>
            <a href="http://www.espn.com" target="blank">Go To ESPN</a>
            <a href="http://www.abcnews.com" target="blank">Go To ABC News</a>
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="blank">Go To Youtube </a>        
       </div>       
</div>
```

controlled by the following css in an external stylesheet

```
div#links a {
        width:550px;
        display:block; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        margin-top:2px; 
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:arial;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-size:9pt;
        border: 3px red ridge;
}
a:hover {
        background-color:navy;
        color:red;
        font-style:italic;
}
```

The display including the hover worked when operated in a standalone situation with the css in the head, however when I move it into a real content area in a page and install the css in the external style sheet the hover no longer works!

Comment: You probably should put in page header reference to your css file <link href="path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: are there additional third party style sheets being applied or is this code added to another stylesheet on the site (compressed and minified) which could have an additional tag overriding your a:hover, if that's the case then the answer by sandeep is correct and this is a matter of specificity

Comment: I have altered the line to reflect the sandeep recommendation and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not linking to your stylesheet the right way.

Either you haven't linked it at all:

```
<link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Or you are using a local path:

You should (almost) always use relative paths for linking to content on the web.

So:

```
http://example.com/style/style.css
```

or

```
file://host/path/style/style.css
```

becomes

```
/style/style/css
```

Comment: This is how I link to the stylesheet in the css folder <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myStyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: @You should add a extra slash in front of the link: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myStyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`. If your `css` folder is in your document root.